# ViewPager and Fragments without xml layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Is possible to create a Layout dinamically in a class that extends Fragment instead of create a static layout in res layout and setting it from onCreateView?

I want create a LinearLayout and add many views (TextView,ImageView,etc) dinamically from fragment.I tried to do this but I've difficulty with the context when I choose a fragment by Split Action Bar

EDIT: I'm not interested to Android Compatibility Lower than API 14 with support library,so is there an easier way for the API 14 and greater?

Answer (score 0):

> Is possible to create a Layout dinamically in a class that extends Fragment instead of >create a static layout in res layout and setting it from onCreateView?

Yes But dont do that.

> I want create a LinearLayout and add many views (TextView,ImageView,etc) dinamically from >fragment.I tried to do this but I've difficulty with the context when I choose a fragment by >Split Action Bar

Define proper xml layouts and inflate them in the code. Follow sample code practices given at 
http://developer.android.com

Comment: this is what I do not want,I want manage the tab (fragmente classes in my project) without xml but as a main activity,for example: if a want put a LinearLayout dinamically in main activity I write LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(this); and after I set the layout by setContentView(layout); is possible to do a similiar thing with a class that extends Fragment?

Comment: As i said. yes it is possible. but trust me if you go through with samples given and will follow proper guidelines. you can design any possible layout using xml and code. follow proper mvc

Comment: I read this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/ but logcat says "NullPointerException" and it depends on viewPager=(ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);